# Matching an item name from Collection A, whose ID is local to Collection B in MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join

I have a two collections,

```
Collection journalists: {
_id: ObjectId("6125f93f5fb88535beecd8ee")
journalist_FirstName: Shyam,
journalist_LastName: Kapoor,
.........
_id: ObjectId("6125f26b5fb88535beecd8c7"),
journalist_FirstName: Kabita
journalist_LastName: Mohan
}
```

```
Collection Stories: {
_id: ObjectId("5ec3ca7fa248314329a5a287"),
journalistId:ObjectId("6125f26b5fb88535beecd8c7"), //local id to journalists collection
storyTitle: "Joining of two tables",
briefDescription: "MongoDB joining of tables",
.....
}
```

Now, if someone just type "Kabita" in the search field, then my query should display the story with title, as "Kabita" is the journalist responsible to create this story.

```
"Joining of two tables"
MongoDB joining of tables
 publish date: 21st Nov 2021
```

My search query needs to consider any words that matches with the name of any journalist from journalists collection, along with any words from either story title or description from stories collection.

Thanks in advance and awaiting for fitting replies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `$lookup` in an `aggregation` will do your job. You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WHn4u0vsn9E).

```
db.journalists.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Stories",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "journalistId",
      "as": "stories_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

Then you have to separe each stories doc to perform the `$match` with `$unwind`

```
  {
    "$unwind": "$stories_docs"
  }
```

After this step you could add a `$match`stage to find the information that you need, if you have to find inside all of those field i will use a `$regex`but the query wont be very efficient...

```
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "journalist_FirstName": {
            "$regex": "tables",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "stories_docs.briefDescription": {
            "$regex": "tables",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "stories_docs.storyTitle": {
            "$regex": "tables",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "stories_docs.keywordName": {
        "$regex": "Heritage",
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Rubén Vega. Your answer did the trick.

Comment: One more doubts. Our aggregation query is returning "stories_docs" which don't have any keyword like "heritage" in keywordName e.g {_id: 123, storyTitle: "Temples in India", briefDescription: "Discussion about Temples in India", keywordName: ["temple City,Bhubaneswar,Odisha,Architecture,Temples"]}. I don't want an story which don't have "heritage" in the keywordName.

Comment: If you want to add another condition in the match you should implemented it. I made an example here. https://mongoplayground.net/p/nlAO1Hcjyc_

Comment: my query is,
db.journalists.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "stories",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "journalistId",
      "as": "stories_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
        
            "stories_docs.keywordName": {
                "$regex": "Heritage",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        
    }
  }
])
I don't want any story, which don't have "heritage" in the keywordName field.

Comment: I just realize that I made a mistake in the query. Your solution will work with this edited code. With this way you will have the journalist separated. If you want to join all their stories you have to add a `$group` to the aggregation